# How to loop through an object and then use array methods on its keys?

Tags: javascript

I see that all the loops for objects returns the key as string and the value, but I want to operate on the keys of the object itself. If I have this object:

```
const data = {
   person1: [
      { id: 1, name: Mike, age: 24 },
      { id: 2, name: Bob, age: 31 }
   ],
   person2: [
      { id: 3, name: Christin, age: 21 },
      { id: 4, name: Michelle, age: 33 }
   ],
}

const removePersonById = (id) => {
   // Check which person the id belongs to and remove that person
   const persons = Object.keys(data).map(person => ...)
}
```

I wanted to loop through data and run `.includes` on each person in order to remove them by the id, but I am at a loss on how to do that.

Comment: do you want to change the original array or just filter out certain users?

Comment: also, if the id you pass into the function is `1`, do you want to remove person1 completely from the array?

Comment: do you want to mutete the data? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Object.values, forEach, indexOf, and splice

Comment: Use `filter()` to remove elements based on a condition.

Comment: @Kinglish Yup I do want to update the original data object to not contain that deleted person. And that's correct, if we pass in id 1, we want to the whole person1 object from the data object.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, yes I do want to mutate the data obj.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all keys and delete that the person you want by id using the `filter()` method

```
const removePersonById = (id) => {
 var all = Object.keys(data);
 for(let person of all){
   data[person] = data[person].filter(a => a.id!=id);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries()` so you can iterate over the keys and values together. Then you can test the value to see if the `id` is found.

Then use the `delete` operator to remove that key from the object.

```
const removePersonById = id => {
    delete data[id];
};
```

```js
const data = {
   person1: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", age: 24 },
      { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 31 }
   ],
   person2: [
      { id: 3, name: "Christin", age: 21 },
      { id: 4, name: "Michelle", age: 33 }
   ],
};

const removePersonById = (id) =>
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value.some(({id: personid}) => personid == id)) {
      delete data[key];
    }
  });

removePersonById(3);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: `del`? really ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz I answer questions for lots of languages, sometimes I get them confused.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
   person1: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", age: 24 },
      { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 31 }
   ],
   person2: [
      { id: 3, name: "Christin", age: 21 },
      { id: 4, name: "Michelle", age: 33 }
   ],
}

const removePersonById = (id) => {
   // Check which person the id belongs to and remove that person
   data = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc,key) => {
   if(data[key].some(person=>person.id===id)) return acc
   acc[key]= data[key]
   return acc
   }, {})
   console.log(`Remove person with ID ${id}: `,data)
}

removePersonById(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the values and find the index. Then splice.

```
const
    removePersonById = id => {
        Object.values(data).forEach(a => {
            const index = a.findIndex(o => o.id === id);
            if (index !== 0) a.splice(index, 1);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.some()`

```js
const data = {
   person1: [
      { id: 1, name: "Mike", age: 24 },
      { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 31 }
   ],
   person2: [
      { id: 3, name: "Christin", age: 21 },
      { id: 4, name: "Michelle", age: 33 }
   ],
}

const removePersonById = (id) => {
   // Check which person the id belongs to and remove that person
   Object.keys(data).map(person => {
     if (data[person].some(p => p.id === id)) delete data[person];
   })
}

removePersonById(3)
console.log(data)
```